# How do I fix the water drop error light on my Hotpoint dryer?

Tags: dryer

I bought a new dryer in 2021 and then moved houses and now the dryer always stops running immediately and displays a red water drop error icon. The water container is completely empty and dry.

How do I figure out what's causing this water error, and how do I fix it? Do I need to start unscrewing the dryer?

I have attached pictures of the water error icon, the front, the back, the model no sticker on the back, and the water container pullout.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does this mean? ... `unscrewing the dryer`

Comment: @jsotola   In the olden days it meant taking it apart and having parts all over the floor to see what was broken.  Too bad they messed everything up by using electronics for everything, and now need a PhD.

Comment: must be a translation from your language ... it would be `disassemble the dryer` in english

Comment: maybe there is a piece of soggy lint on a sensor somewhere

Comment: The owner's manual for that model will explain the panel lights and error codes. If you don't have a copy, they can often be found online.

Answer (score 0):

Try filling the water reservoir?  Is there an operating manual with troubleshooting answers?  Sorry that these new machines have so much added complexity which doesn't help dry clothes but is only there for marketing!  Change is not necessarily progress...

Comment: Hi Haven,  this site does not run like a forum. So, no rants please. Was this supposed to be an answer? Is there s basis for it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/166922)

Comment: No "rant", just an opinion based on observation and experience!  There is not enough information to make a proper diagnosis therefore no correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hotpoint Ariston Dryer User's Manual

**[image]Lights on or flashing**

Problem: Water tank - The water tank is full.

Solution: Empty the water tank. Refer to the section Care & Maintenance below.

**CARE AND MAINTENANCE**

Unplug the dryer during the cleaning and maintenance
procedures.

[image]Emptying the water tank after each cycle (see Fig. A).
Pull the container out of the dryer and empty it into a sink
or other suitable drain, then place it back. Do not use the dryer
without having inserted the container back in place.

**If the procedure does not work, call the tech service to check the electronic circus/censor.**

[image]

Comment: From the question: **The water container is completely empty and dry.**

Comment: @OrganicMarble See and read til the last sentence :)

Comment: So, your answer is to call the service man?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Unfortunately, yes, I know I would do so after checking the manual.